# How does configuring a service reference affect my project?

Tags: visual-studio, service-reference

I have a C# Visual Studio console application with a service reference. The company providing the service offers two API's one for test and one for live. They are supposed to be essentially the same service but with different URL's to different servers.

When I right click the service reference and choose Configure Service Reference, I am able to enter the the URL for the live service; and my project compiles properly.

I am new to this and am not really sure if I should be reconfiguring the service or if I should be deleting it and re-adding it in? I don't know if there are .config files I should be changing or cleaning manually.

So I guess my question is - are there pitfalls or better practices for this process that I should be aware of?

Any advice greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with Service References myself and so far never had any problem with just updating the service reference. If you like/need to change the configuration, it is possible by editing the .config file that gets generated